# How to get JSON response from public API into JSON object?

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest

I'm attempting to get some data from the OpenWeatherMap API. When I send the request with the required API key and location data, everything returns back fine. The returned data appears to be in JSON format. However, when I perform the JSON.parse() function on the string, it gives an error of "unexpected end of input".

One thing that I found interesting was that if I was to store the string into a variable and then proceed to execute the function in Chrome's debug console, it completes fine.

```
let jsonData;
let jsonActual;
function GetWeather(city, country){
  Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  Http.open("GET", weatherUrl + city + "," + country + weatherKey);
  Http.send();
  Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
    jsonData = Http.response;
    jsonActual = JSON.parse(jsonData.toString());

  }
}
```

On using the console:

```
x = JSON.parse(jsonData) // Completes successfully
```

Comment: You're not checking the `readyState` in your `onreadystatechange` event handler. The response will only be complete when [`readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) is `complete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `readyState` is never checked if it is `complete`:

```
Http.onreadystatechange = e => {
    if (this.readyState == "complete") {
        jsonData = Http.response;
        jsonActual = JSON.parse(jsonData.toString());
    }
}
```

You could also check against `4`:

```
Http.onreadystatechange = e => {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
        jsonData = Http.response;
        jsonActual = JSON.parse(jsonData.toString());
    }
}
```

And you could just make it even simpler and use `fetch`:

```
let jsonData;
let jsonActual;
function GetWeather(city, country){
    fetch(`${weatherUrl}${city},${country}${weatherKey}`).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
        jsonData = res;
        jsonActual = JSON.parse(res);
    });
}
```

Comment: `res.json()` returns parsed array/object ... pointless to JSON.parse() it

Comment: Oh yes sorry @charlietfl.

Answer (score 1):

In your function `onreadystatechange` you have

```
Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
    jsonData = Http.response;
    jsonActual = JSON.parse(jsonData.toString());

  }
```

Try to do this instead:

```
Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
         jsonData = Http.response;
         jsonActual = JSON.parse(jsonData.toString());
    }

  }
```